# Generating a price from a HTML select form using a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, quote

I'm building a quote generator for a website, the form uses three  dropdown boxes. I'm just starting to get my head around JS so I need some help passing the selected data from the HTML to the JS and returning a quote. I've created a function which takes three arguments(service, bedrooms, furnishing) which you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/alan1986/g3bKV/ I'm sure there's a neater way I could write this function which would take far less code.

Anyway that's the least of my worries, this function might be far too big but at least it works. I've been researching answers for how to combine selected options from a form and pass them to a function and I can see how it would work using integers but I need to use strings. So here's some code I've been working with for getting the selected option from the HTML and then returning the result to the page - my question is how do I link this info to the function to return the result?

```
function output(){
    document.write(document.getElementById("service").value + "</br>");
    document.write(document.getElementById("bedrooms").value + "</br>");
    document.write(document.getElementById("furnishing").value + "</br>");

    var results = document.getElementById("service").value + "<br>" +
                  document.getElementById("bedrooms").value + "<br>" +
                  document.getElementById("furnishing").value + "<br>";

    document.getElementById("yourOutputDiv").innerHTML = results;
```

Comment: what do you want the returned quote to look like? ##£ as a string? when i hear 'quote' i think total but i'm guessing that's not what you're looking for

Comment: yep I'd like the result to be a string i.e. "£75" which I'd like to appear after "=" in the div below the form. I want the three selected options to be passed to the function as its three arguments and when the matching three options are found the appropriate string such "£75" is returned. Do I need to build a function on top of this function or send three option to an array and then pass the array to the function? I would be equally happy to have a submit button below the form which when clicked returned the quote. Is there a simpler way of writing my function? thanks

Comment: can you take my code below and add some intelligence to set your string values? or do you need help with that?

Comment: I need help with that please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a singleton that attaches an `onchange` event to each form element and updates the this.data values on change. From looking at your code and your jsfiddle (which didn't work for me) this approach may not make a lot of sense. I've tested this on my local machine and it works

```
<script>
    var quoteMaker = {
        data : {
            'services':null,
            'bedrooms':null,
            'furnishing':null,
            'quoteString':''
        },
        servicesListener : function(){
           this.data.services = document.getElementById('service').options[document.getElementById('service').selectedIndex].text;
        },
        bedroomsListener : function(){
           this.data.bedrooms = document.getElementById('bedrooms').options[document.getElementById('bedrooms').selectedIndex].text;
        },
        furnishingListener : function(){
           this.data.furnishing = document.getElementById('furnishing').options[document.getElementById('furnishing').selectedIndex].text;
        },
        changeData : function(divObj){
            this.data.quoteString='';
            if( divObj.id == 'service' ){
                this.servicesListener();
            }else if( divObj.id == 'bedrooms' ){
                this.bedroomsListener();
            }else if( divObj.id == 'furnishing' ){
                this.furnishingListener();
            }
            this.updateQuote();
        },
    updateQuote : function() {
      if (this.data.services == "Inventory" &&this.data.bedrooms =="1" && this.data.furnishing == "Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£70"; 
      if (this.data.services == "Inventory" &&this.data.bedrooms =="2" && this.data.furnishing == "Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£75";
      if (this.data.services == "Inventory" &&this.data.bedrooms =="3" && this.data.furnishing == "Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£80";
      if (this.data.services == "Inventory" &&this.data.bedrooms =="4" && this.data.furnishing == "Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£85";
      if (this.data.services == "Inventory" &&this.data.bedrooms =="5" && this.data.furnishing == "Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£90";
      if (this.data.services == "Inventory" &&this.data.bedrooms =="6+" && this.data.furnishing == "Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£100";

      if (this.data.services == "Inventory" &&this.data.bedrooms =="1" && this.data.furnishing == "Part Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£60"; 
      if (this.data.services == "Inventory" &&this.data.bedrooms =="2" && this.data.furnishing == "Part Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£65";
      if (this.data.services == "Inventory" &&this.data.bedrooms =="3" && this.data.furnishing == "Part Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£70";
      if (this.data.services == "Inventory" &&this.data.bedrooms =="4" && this.data.furnishing == "Part Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£75";
      if (this.data.services == "Inventory" &&this.data.bedrooms =="5" && this.data.furnishing == "Part Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£80";
      if (this.data.services == "Inventory" &&this.data.bedrooms =="6+" && this.data.furnishing == "Part Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£85";

      if (this.data.services == "Inventory" &&this.data.bedrooms =="1" && this.data.furnishing == "Unfurnished (except for white goods)") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£55"; 
      if (this.data.services == "Inventory" &&this.data.bedrooms =="2" && this.data.furnishing == "Unfurnished (except for white goods)") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£60";
      if (this.data.services == "Inventory" &&this.data.bedrooms =="3" && this.data.furnishing == "Unfurnished (except for white goods)") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£65";
      if (this.data.services == "Inventory" &&this.data.bedrooms =="4" && this.data.furnishing == "Unfurnished (except for white goods)") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£70";
      if (this.data.services == "Inventory" &&this.data.bedrooms =="5" && this.data.furnishing == "Unfurnished (except for white goods)") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£75";
      if (this.data.services == "Inventory" &&this.data.bedrooms =="6+" && this.data.furnishing == "Unfurnished (except for white goods)") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£80";


      if (this.data.services == "Check-In" &&this.data.bedrooms =="1" && this.data.furnishing == "Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£50"; 
      if (this.data.services == "Check-In" &&this.data.bedrooms =="2" && this.data.furnishing == "Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£55";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-In" &&this.data.bedrooms =="3" && this.data.furnishing == "Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£60";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-In" &&this.data.bedrooms =="4" && this.data.furnishing == "Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£65";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-In" &&this.data.bedrooms =="5" && this.data.furnishing == "Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£70";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-In" &&this.data.bedrooms =="6+" && this.data.furnishing == "Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£75";

      if (this.data.services == "Check-In" &&this.data.bedrooms =="1" && this.data.furnishing == "Part Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£40"; 
      if (this.data.services == "Check-In" &&this.data.bedrooms =="2" && this.data.furnishing == "Part Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£45";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-In" &&this.data.bedrooms =="3" && this.data.furnishing == "Part Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£50";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-In" &&this.data.bedrooms =="4" && this.data.furnishing == "Part Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£55";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-In" &&this.data.bedrooms =="5" && this.data.furnishing == "Part Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£60";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-In" &&this.data.bedrooms =="6+" && this.data.furnishing == "Part Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£65";

      if (this.data.services == "Check-In" &&this.data.bedrooms =="1" && this.data.furnishing == "Unfurnished (except for white goods)") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£35"; 
      if (this.data.services == "Check-In" &&this.data.bedrooms =="2" && this.data.furnishing == "Unfurnished (except for white goods)") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£40";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-In" &&this.data.bedrooms =="3" && this.data.furnishing == "Unfurnished (except for white goods)") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£45";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-In" &&this.data.bedrooms =="4" && this.data.furnishing == "Unfurnished (except for white goods)") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£50";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-In" &&this.data.bedrooms =="5" && this.data.furnishing == "Unfurnished (except for white goods)") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£55";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-In" &&this.data.bedrooms =="6+" && this.data.furnishing == "Unfurnished (except for white goods)") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£60";


      if (this.data.services == "Check-Out" &&this.data.bedrooms =="1" && this.data.furnishing == "Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£55"; 
      if (this.data.services == "Check-Out" &&this.data.bedrooms =="2" && this.data.furnishing == "Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£60";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-Out" &&this.data.bedrooms =="3" && this.data.furnishing == "Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£65";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-Out" &&this.data.bedrooms =="4" && this.data.furnishing == "Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£70";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-Out" &&this.data.bedrooms =="5" && this.data.furnishing == "Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£75";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-Out" &&this.data.bedrooms =="6+" && this.data.furnishing == "Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£80";

      if (this.data.services == "Check-Out" &&this.data.bedrooms =="1" && this.data.furnishing == "Part Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£45"; 
      if (this.data.services == "Check-Out" &&this.data.bedrooms =="2" && this.data.furnishing == "Part Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£50";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-Out" &&this.data.bedrooms =="3" && this.data.furnishing == "Part Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£55";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-Out" &&this.data.bedrooms =="4" && this.data.furnishing == "Part Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£60";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-Out" &&this.data.bedrooms =="5" && this.data.furnishing == "Part Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£65";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-Out" &&this.data.bedrooms =="6+" && this.data.furnishing == "Part Furnished") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£70";

      if (this.data.services == "Check-Out" &&this.data.bedrooms =="1" && this.data.furnishing == "Unfurnished (except for white goods)") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£40"; 
      if (this.data.services == "Check-Out" &&this.data.bedrooms =="2" && this.data.furnishing == "Unfurnished (except for white goods)") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£45";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-Out" &&this.data.bedrooms =="3" && this.data.furnishing == "Unfurnished (except for white goods)") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£50";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-Out" &&this.data.bedrooms =="4" && this.data.furnishing == "Unfurnished (except for white goods)") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£55";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-Out" &&this.data.bedrooms =="5" && this.data.furnishing == "Unfurnished (except for white goods)") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£60";
      if (this.data.services == "Check-Out" &&this.data.bedrooms =="6+" && this.data.furnishing == "Unfurnished (except for white goods)") 
         this.data.quoteString = "£65";
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML=this.data.quoteString;
},
        init: function(){

        }   
    }
    quoteMaker.init();
</script>


    <div id="form">
    <p class="lead">Complete the form for an instant quote</p>
        <form name="quote-maker" action="">
            <p>Select service<br />
            <select id="service" name="services" onchange="quoteMaker.changeData(this);">
                <option value="Inventory">Inventory</option>
                <option value="Check-In">Check-In</option>
                <option value="Check-Out">Check-Out</option>
            </select></p>        
            <p class="lead">How many bedrooms does the property have?<br />
            <select id="bedrooms" name="bedrooms" onchange="quoteMaker.changeData(this);">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="5">6+</option>
            </select></p> 
            <p class="lead">Is the property furnished or unfurnished?<br />
            <select id="furnishing" name="furnishing" onchange="quoteMaker.changeData(this);">
                <option value="1">Furnished</option>
                <option value="2">Part Furnished </option>
                <option value="3">Unfurnished (except for white goods)</option>
            </select></p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="quote"></div>
```

Note: I cleaned up your html.  Wrap all your `<select>` inputs in a single form

Comment: Thanks for your help, so with this code selecting different options returns the selected options below the form. What I want to do is pass those three options as arguments through my function and when a matching 'if' statement is found it returns a corresponding value. For example if someone selects "Inventory" + "1" + "Furnished" these would be passed to the quote function as its (service, bedrooms, furnishing) arguments and when the matching 'if' statement was found: if (service == "Inventory" && bedrooms == "1" && furnishing == "Furnished") 
     return ("£70");

Comment: ok. modified my updateQuote method with your function logic.  take it from here

Comment: Thanks so much, you've really helped, that's working a charm :D

Comment: you neglected a space in your string for `"Unfurnished (except for white goods)"` which caused that condition to always fail.  updated my example.  working now.

Comment: Oh I just realised the unfurnished wasn't working, thanks again, so I needed the space before the parentheses?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38626/discussion-between-b-dubb-and-alan-sutherland)